# Angular 2 Reuse component selector

Tags: typescript, angular, components

I want to re-use an component selector which looks like this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'expression-builder',
template: `
    <div class="container">
       <expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression" [expressions]="expressions"></expression>
       <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
`,
})
```

But if I set it like this in an other component it will not show anything:

```
@Component({
selector: 'expression',
template: `
<div class="row">
<!-- First Select -->
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
            <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
                {{ p.selectorName }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

<!-- Second Select -->
    <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-3': prototype?.valueType !== 'Set', 'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}" *ngIf="prototype">
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="expression.constraint">
            <option *ngFor="#constraint of prototype.constraints" [value]="constraint">
                {{ constraint }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

<!-- Third Select -->
    <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-3': prototype?.valueType !== 'Set', 'col-xs-2': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}">

       <div>{{expression | json}}</div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click)="deleteExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Expression Set selector -->
    <div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
       <expression-builder></expression-builder>
    </div>
</div>
`,
directives: [ExpressionBuilderComponent]
})
```

If i set it here i well get the following error:

```
Unexpected directive value 'undefined'
```

I want to re-use the template when in my case `valueType = Set`

Comment: I don't get it. What is a "selector element"?

Comment: I also can't see an component selector. No idea at all what this question is about.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer lol i understand why you had no idea it was the wrong code -.-''

Comment: It's still quite vague what this question is about. You can't use `*ngIf` in `index.html`.

Comment: The `*ngIf` is in a component where i want to re use the template. I am trying to create a plunkr to show you, but it is not working...

Comment: Just post all the necessary code to replicate your problem here, as part of your question.

Comment: @ManoDestra this creates a better view also my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617468/angular-2-unexpected-directive-value-undefined/36623575?noredirect=1#comment60844576_36623575

Answer (score 0):

In whatever `component` you set this:

```
<!-- Expression Set selector -->
 <div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
     <expression-builder></expression-builder>
 </div>
```

You have to add the class name of `expression-builder` to the `directives` attribute of the `@Component()` to let angular2 know what kind of directives/components you are using in your template.

For instance if the classname of the `expression-builder` is `ExpressionBuilderComponent` and the classname of the parent component is `ExpressionSetComponent` you'll get something like this:

**expression.set.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector : 'expression-set',
  template : `
     <div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
         <expression-builder></expression-builder>
     </div>
  `,
  directives : [
    ExpressionBuilderComponent //<-- this is kinda important
  ]
})
export class ExpressionSetComponent {

}
```

Comment: I'll get this : `Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'ExpressionComponent'`

Comment: i'll edit my question as you can see, what is wrong?