# Angular 2 Unexpected directive value 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, angular, components

I have 2 components, I want to re-use one in the other so this is the component I want to re-use the ExpressionBuilderComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'expression-builder',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
           <expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression" [expressions]="expressions"></expression>
           <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    `,
    directives: [ExpressionComponent]
})
```

Than I have the ExpressionComponent  like this :

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'expression',
    template: `
  <div class="row">
    <!-- First Select -->
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
                <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
                    {{ p.selectorName }}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>

 <!-- Expression Set selector -->
    <div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
       <expression-builder></expression-builder>
    </div>
```

Here is a **[PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqNXjd?p=preview)** and it should show Test twice because I use `<expression-builder>` twice.

In my project it is showing as an empty element, In this screenshot you can see how it is rendered out:[image]

Can someone please help me out on this, how is it possible that in this case it is working?

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/recursive-treeview-in-angular-2.0

Comment: To begin with you need to reference `ExpressionBuilderComponent` by writing `directives: [ExpressionBuilderComponent]`. After that, further down the component tree you should write `directives: [forwardRef(() => ExpressionBuilderComponent)]` if you want to reference it again. Did you try that?

Comment: Use https://plnkr.co/edit/nW00uu?p=info as a template to start from.

Comment: Plunker seems to be working again.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you please help me out I get this error and don't know why he is failing at that point? `Error during instantiation of Token Promise<ComponentRef>!.` https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqNXjd?p=preview

Comment: Is there a reason you have `directives: [ExpressionComponent]` on `ExpressionBuilderComonent`? Doesn't look like you use it in the view.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'll added the `directives: [ExpressionBuilderComponent]`  with no reason someone gave me that as answer. But the `[ExpressionComponent]` is necessary to render the expressions?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Does the Plunker really contain what you want to demonstrate? I don't see where you use `<expression-builder>` twice.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In the `index.html` and in `expression.component`

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, if these two components depend on each other I don't think there is a way to solve it. Creating a duplicate of one of these two component might help to break the cycle.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer hmm but that will be not the most efficient way to do it

Comment: If no other way is possible, then this **is** the most efficient way ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you maybe have some time to join me in this chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109229/discussion-between-beginnerprogrammer-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: To your update: In the treeview it depends only on itself not circularily on another component that depends on the first. Actually this might be a hint how you can solve your problem. Instead of creating creating a copy of one component, you could combine both into one and pass a property value to make it behave like the one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `ExpressionBuilderComponent` from directives the error goes away:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'expression',
    ...
    //    directives: [ExpressionBuilderComponent]
})
export class ExpressionComponent implements OnInit {
```

if it is necessary I don't know a solution. AFAIK circular dependencies between classes in TypeScript can only be resolve using interfaces and I don't know how that would work with `directives`.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vc73df?p=preview)

BTW: this is how your Plunker should have looked like. A minimial example that allows to reproduce the problem. You added way to much code that is entirely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Sorry man, I thought you could had a better overview with that so that I am not forget something to mention

Comment: It's really hard to read and understand code you don't know the purpose of and find which of this code might actually be related to the problem. If you report a problem try hard to get rid of as much code as possible while keeping the actual problem reproducible. You'll get much better response in shorter time.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip I will keep this in mind in the future :) So you do not know any solution for this issue right now?

Comment: What about removing `ExpressionBuilderComponent` from `directives` in `ExpressionComponent`? I don't see why you'd need it.

Comment: Okay, but than again its component selector is empty and is not showing the template I want.

Comment: "Its" ? No idea what you mean.

Comment: That re-used `<expression-builder></expression-builder>`